# Cannot submit form insider javascript popover with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to submit a bootstrap popover form with php, however it is not populating the table. any suggestions?

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[rel='android']").popover({
html: 'true', 
content : '<div id="popOver-input"><p id="coming-soon">Coming March 2014</p><p>Be the first to know when buddyTruk goes live!</p><form class="form-horizontal" action="temp.php"  method="post"><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="emailFuture"  placeholder="Email"/><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="comingSoon" type="submit"   value="comingSoon">Submit</button></form></div>'
});
});
```

php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['comingSoon']) && strlen($_POST['email'])>0)
{
$coming_soon=$_POST['emailFuture']; 
mysql_connect("*****", "****", "*****") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("buddyTruk") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE coming_soon ADD PRIMARY KEY (email)");
mysql_query("REPLACE INTO `coming_soon` VALUES ('$coming_soon')"); 

 } 


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no input with name `email` but you trying : `$_POST['email']`, So, change the name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[rel='android']").popover({
html: 'true', 
content : '<div id="popOver-input"><p id="coming-soon">Coming March 2014</p><p>Be the first to know when buddyTruk goes live!</p><form class="form-horizontal" action="temp.php"  method="post"><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email"  placeholder="Email"/><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="comingSoon" type="submit"   value="comingSoon">Submit</button></form></div>'
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `name` of your email input in the form is `emailFuture`.  So modify the conditional:

```
if (isset($_POST['comingSoon']) && strlen($_POST['emailFuture'])>0)
{
    // insert
}
```

I recommend checking that `$_POST['emailFuture']` is set also, just in case something goes wrong you don't raise an unnecessary exception.  A good substitute for `isset() && strlen() > 0` is [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty), so: `(isset($_POST['comingSoon']) && !empty($_POST['emailFuture']))`